# Name typed by user to star java program

Tags: java

I am new to programming and got stuck on a task. It says that user should input their name and the size of it and then it would be printed in stars with that size, also it should use loops in this program not just sout stars.
I have no idea on how to approach this problem so I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me an idea :)

What I have tried so far is:
(update):
i was able to do my whole coding and reach the thing i want, but what i'am stuck in a point, where if user update the size which is n , how i can use it in my whole switch while printing where Pattern(A) prints star version of letter

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option = 0;


        while (option != 3) {

            System.out.println("Hello, Welcome to Işık NameIt program. ");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("The following options are available for you:\n" +
                    "1) Display a name\n" +
                    "2) Change the size\n" +
                    "3) Exit Program");
            System.out.print("Choose an option: ");

            option = input.nextInt();
            int n = 5;



            switch (option) {

                case 1:
                    System.out.print("What is your name?! ");
                    String name = input.next();

                    for(int i=0; i<=name.length()-1; i++) {
                       char letter =  name.charAt(i);

                       switch (letter){
                           case 'a':
                               PatternA(n);
                               break;
                           case 'y':
                               PatternY(n);
                               break;
                           case 'h':
                               PatternH(n)
                               break;
                           case 'm':
                               PatternM(n)
                               break;
                       }
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.print("What is the new size? ");
                    int nupdate = input.nextInt();
            }

        }
    }

    public static void PatternA(int n) {
        // Outer for loop for number of lines
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            // Inner for loop for logic execution
            for (int j = 0; j <= n / 2; j++) {

                // prints two column lines
                if ((j == 0 || j == n / 2) && i != 0 ||

                        // print first line of alphabet
                        i == 0 && j != 0 && j != n / 2 ||

                        // prints middle line
                        i == n / 2)

                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
```

Comment: add from "int option .. " to the end of the switch inside a while(true){...}

Comment: You don't need the switch statement.  Get the size of the input from ouput.length.  Then print out a star in a for loop that loops a number of 'output.length' times.  That is if I understand that you want to print out a selection of stars that has the same length as the input.

Comment: Or better a `do-while(...)` @AlbertoSinigaglia, `while(true)` if not used responsibly could lead to infinite loops

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are expecting as your output, if you provided a sample of that it would be helpful. However, with the way you have your program implemented right now you will want to throw your switch statement inside of a while loop to continue executing the program until a 3 is input by the user.

```
while (option != 3)
{
    switch (option)
    {
        // code
    }
    // code
    option = input.nextInt();
}
```

Within that while block you can execute whatever statements you want when the user inputs their specified option. Depending on the requirements of the code you should also consider validating the user input. What happens if they don't put in a 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: sorry for being late, my program has to repeat that welcome... thing until user input 3, also if he select size and set it to a new number, and then type his name it should be prined in star version

Comment: That's what a while loop will do for you. It will check to see if your user input is a 1, 2 or a 3 and then execute the code within it until the user inputs a 3. You need to make sure to prompt the user again for the input within the while loop so you can give the loop a chance to exit. You also will need to add some validation to your code to ensure the user did not type a 4, 5, or any other number/letter that is not a 1, 2, or 3 or your code will be error prone.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Hello, Welcome to Işık NameIt program. ");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("The following options are available for you:\n" +
            "1) Display a name\n" +
            "2) Change the size\n" +
            "3) Exit Program");
    System.out.print("Choose an option: ");

    int option = input.nextInt();
    int size = option.length;

    while(option !=3){
    switch (option){

        case 1:
             for(int index = 0; index <= size; index++) {
                 System.out.print("*");
             }
             System.out.println(" ");
        case 2:
            System.out.print("What is the new size? ");
            size = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
        case 3:
            break;

      }
   }
}
```